# How can I find commits in which a specified change happened?

Tags: git

How can i find commits in which a specified change happened? In this case, neither the exact filename nor the exact linenumber are known. Its basically a raw search.  I.E. i search for the commits in which a line contains a change from "before" to "after".

ie. commit history as follows:

- Commit A (Base)

  ```
    The line without change 
    The text *before* the change
    Another line without relevant change, before
  ```
- Commit B:

  ```
    The line without change 
  - The text *before* the change
  + The text *after* the change
    Another line without relevant change, before
  ```
- commit C:

  ```
    The line without change
    The line of code *after* the change
  - Another line without relevant change, before
  + Another line without a relevant change
  ```

As a result i just want to have the hash for commit B. I basically need all changes in all files.

Comment: Just for my own understanding, should the -/+ not be swapped in your `Commit B`?

Comment: oops, yes, should be swapped

Comment: Good, I was really concerned I was being thick =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git log -G<search pattern>`. For more info, see the second part of [this article](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-searching-for-commits.html).

Comment: -G for a regex, or -S for a fixed string

Comment: This works, but it produces a lot of false positives. I have not yet found a way to surpress those commits that do not contain the "after" change.